# What is the underlying representation of BLOB data when I export it?

Tags: mysql, blob

When I export a blob object to an SQL file, I get some thing like this for a blob field:

```
0x4f3a383a227374644.....,
```

## Questions

- I would like to know how the BLOB is actually converted to the above format?
- What is its underlying representation?

Comment: It's the raw data in hexidecimal format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [**`mysqldump`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html), you can specify the hexadecimal format for BLOB data

```
mysqldump -u... -p... --hex-blob --all-databases ...
```

Here is the help on `hex-blob` in `mysqldump`

```
$ mysqldump --help | grep -A 1 "blob" | head -2
  --hex-blob          Dump binary strings (BINARY, VARBINARY, BLOB) in
                      hexadecimal format.
```